# Establish if time portion of getdate() is in a specific interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
Index, Time_start, Time_stop
```

The `Time` columns are of type `time(7)`.

I need a view (or select statement) that will list the three columns along with a fourth column that will state `In` or `Out` if the moment when the script is run is or not between `Time_start` and `Time_stop` for each row.

I tried using a case statement:

```
case getdate() between Time_start and Time_stop then 'Yes'
```

but it's not working.

Comment: `CONVERT(time,getdate())`?

Comment: "case when" not "case"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by converting the value of `GETDATE()` to a `TIME`:

```
-- you may need to change these times to values relevant to your local time
DECLARE @time1 AS TIME(7) = '12:15'
DECLARE @time2 AS TIME(7) = '16:15'

SELECT @time1 AS Time_start, @time2 AS Time_stop
INTO #tmp_time

SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(TIME(7), GETDATE()) BETWEEN Time_start AND Time_stop 
            THEN 'In' 
            ELSE 'Out' 
       END
FROM #tmp_time

DROP TABLE #tmp_time
```

**Caveat**

This will not filter dates, so I assume that all records in the recordset you are querying are for the same day, otherwise this will take records from other days too.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with a `CASE` expression, but you need the `TIME` portion of the `GETDATE()` as mentioned in comments:

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) BETWEEN Time_start AND Time_stop 
              THEN 'In' ELSE 'Out' 
         END AS In_Out
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

consider to add computed column 'state' with case statement

```
               alter table tbl
               add column STATE AS 
               CASE WHEN CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) 
               BETWEEN 
               Time_start AND Time_stop 
               THEN 'In' 
               ELSE 'Out' 
               END
```